# Page Title repeating

Tags: pages, blog, wp-title

I am a newbie in WordPress and our website page titles are repeating. That is the first problem. The second problem appears to be that there is a space missing between the repetition.

I have attached a diagram to demonstrate this issue. In the attached diagram note that at the top left of Chrome our blog's name is "Snowball Blog". Instead of a space after that, there is no space, and then We have the subtitle of the blog (in this case Hosting). After the word hosting this then appears ">> Snowball Blog".

This happens on all pages, for example, "Snowball BlogMeet the Team >> Snowball Blog". I am not that familiar with coding so I would probably need simple instructions! :-)

Here is a link to the hosting page of our Blog: [Hosting page on our blog](http://www.snowball.co.za/blog/hosting/)

[I wanted to post a link to the image I captured but my reputation is still too low! Please visit the URL above to see an example of the problem!]

Comment: Please, read the [About] page to know how this site works. This may be helpful to understand what's going on with your theme: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

look into header.php of your theme;

`<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>`

when you use a seo plugin, you can control the meta title with the plugin;
change that line to:

`<title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>`